# Editing XML content with PowerShell working locally but not via Invoke-Command

Tags: xml, powershell, invoke-command

I'm trying to script the removal of a XML node using PowerShell from a .xml file on a remote computer.

My `Invoke-Command` scriptblock is:

```bsh
$remoteResult = Invoke-Command -ComputerName myserver.com -ScriptBlock {
    Param($FolderName) 

    $xmlFilePath = "c:\foo\Folders.xml"
    $localLog="c:\foo\removefolder.txt"

    [XML]$XMLContent = Get-Content $xmlFilePath -Encoding UTF8
    Write-Output $FolderName | Out-File $localLog -Append
    Write-Output "Entering loop" | Out-File $localLog -Append
    foreach ($Folder in $XMLContent.Folders) {
        $XMLFolderName = $Folder.SelectSingleNode("//Name[.='$FolderName']")
        Write-Output "Folder = $folder" | Out-String | Out-File $localLog -Append
        Write-Output "XMLUserName = $XMLFolderName" | Out-File $localLog -Append
        if ($XMLFolderName.'#text' -eq $FolderName) {
            $XMLUserName.'#text' | Out-File $localLog -Append
            Write-Output "User entry found for $FolderName, removing." | Out-File $localLog -Append
            $XMLFolderName.ParentNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild($XMLFolderName.ParentNode)
        }
        Write-Output "Folder entry not found?" | Out-File $localLog -Append
    }
    Write-Output "End loop" | Out-File $localLog -Append
    $XMLContent.Save($xmlFilePath)
} -ArgumentList $remfolder *>&1
```

I've added a load of `Out-File` statements to generate a log on the remote machine to see what the state of things are during the script execution. I can see the `$FolderName` is being passed correctly, then I get:

```
Entering loop
Folder = System.Xml.XmlElement

XMLUserName =
User entry not found?
End loop
```

If I get it to `Out-File` the `Get-Content` line it successfully reads the file and saves it to the log, so the .xml file is being read successfully.

If I copy the above code to the remote server and run it directly from there without the `Invoke-Command` statement, and manually pass the value of `$FolderName`, it works fine and removes the XML node as expected.

So I'm not sure what is happening differently when it's run remotely.

Edit:
As requested, here's an example of the XML format being accessed.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Folders>
  <Folder>
    <Name>Folder1</Name>
    <Location>\\server.com\share$\folder\Folder1</Location>
    <Limitations />
    <Description>Folder One</Description>
    <CustomField />
    <UserPermissions />
    <GroupPermissions>
      <Permission>
        <IdentityName>Folder One</IdentityName>
        <ListRestriction>
          <Type>Deny</Type>
          <Extensions />
        </ListRestriction>
      </Permission>
    </GroupPermissions>
  </Folder>
  <Folder>
    <Name>Folder2</Name>
    <Location>\\server.com\share$\folder\Folder2</Location>
    <Limitations />
    <Description>Folder Two</Description>
    <CustomField />
    <UserPermissions>
      <Permission>
        <IdentityName>Folder Two</IdentityName>
        <ListRestriction>
          <Type>Deny</Type>
          <Extensions />
        </ListRestriction>
      </Permission>
    </UserPermissions>
    <GroupPermissions />
  </Folder>
```

So for instance in the script I'm assigning $FolderName as "Folder2". When run locally it successfully removed that entire Folder node, remotely it doesn't.

Comment: You never assigned `$XMLUserName` anywhere

Comment: Please show a sample of your XML and input values.

Comment: Ansgar: Done

trebleCode: XMLUserName= is just text, the variable displayed on that line is $XMLFolderName which is defined above there in the SelectSingleNode statement.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue... the code itself was essentially fine, but I've been falling foul of the fact that when dealing with XML, PowerShell essentially becomes case sensitive.

So for example where the actual folder entry in XML is "MyFolder", and I set $FolderName as "myfolder", in any other comparison situation $FolderName -eq "MyFolder" would be true, but not when "MyFolder" is selected from XML.